# nxt_rviz_plugin with Rosjava

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I'm using the **nxt_lejos_proxy** package and **rviz**. 
I would like to use the **nxt_rviz_plugin**, which displays data from a nxt_msgs::Range message as a cone. I've set the topic to /ultrasonic_sensor, but when i run the simulation I got:

```
Status:Warning
   Topic No messages received
```

Using **rostopic echo /ultrasonic_sensor** I can see that the ranges detected by the ultrasonic sensor are published on the /ultrasonic_sensor topic.
But looking in the class ROSProxy.java I've seen that the message published on that topic is a **sensor_msgs/Range** and not a **nxt_msgs/Range**.
Could this be the cause of the problem?And how can i solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40894/nxt_rviz_plugin-with-rosjava/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved publishing a message of type nxt_msgs/Range on a custom defined topic called /custom_ultrasonic_sensor and passing this topic to nxt_rviz_plugin.

---

Originally posted by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) with karma: 255 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0